# NSImage: set a pixel's colour directly

Tags: swift, macos

I'm making a very simple art package for pixel art on MacOS. I am currently drawing directly to an NSImage using CGRect's fill() function. This is all well and good, but this function composites onto the existing colour. This means that if I want to paint a colour with an alpha value, or just erase the pixel to clear, it combines the colour with the existing one. As a result, I cannot use this code to implement an 'eraser' tool.

I've tried shifting to CGImage, but cannot find a way to set pixel data directly. I've also tried shifting to BitmapRef, but one does not exist on a newly created NSImage and I can't quite figure out how to ensure one is created correctly and in a usable form.

Can anyone suggest what the best-practice way of implementing an 'eraser' tool would be, or at least give me a hint as to the correct kind of object to use as an image representation for editing would be? I've seen some documentation that suggested CGImage was the way to go, but (for reasons noted above) have not been able to find a reasonable solution.

I guess an ideal solution would be some way to set a compositing operation of the context to 'clear' but I can't see how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Why is it whenever I post a question here, after trying for several hours, I almost always find the answer about ten minutes later?

The simple answer is that the compositing operation for the NSGraphicsContext object does not affect NSRect's fill() function. Instead there is a variant form of that function fill(using: NSCompositingOperation) which you use thus:

```
rect.fill(using: .clear)
```